# Fortran pointer attribute to type declarations

Tags: pointers, struct, fortran, intel-fortran

I have the following type

```
  type OCTREE_TYPE
     real                          :: box(2,3)
     integer, allocatable          :: icells(:)
     integer                       :: num_point
     integer                       :: depth
     type(OCTREE_TYPE), pointer    :: parent      => NULL()
     type(OCTREE_TYPE), pointer    :: children(:) => NULL()
  end type OCTREE_TYPE
```

Now, when I declare a **variable** of this data-type, what is the difference between this declaration

```
   type(OCTREE_TYPE),pointer        :: octree_node
```

and this

```
  type(OCTREE_TYPE)        :: octree_node
```

besides that one of them is a pointer and the other is not.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean.  If you don't add the `pointer` attribute to the object it isn't a pointer.  That seems obvious, so what aspects would you like us to address?

Comment: When you declare it as a pointer, it states that your `octree_type` has two members (`parent` and `children`) that contain the address in memory of two `octree_type` objects.. You can access them by means of the pointer. If you do not declare the pointer it would mean that both `parent` and `children` are octrees. The downside is that you would create a recursive tree of infinite memory as the first declaration of an `octree_type` would contain a member that is  an `octree_type` itself, that would contain a member that is  an `octree_type` itself, that would contain a member that is  an ...

Comment: ... that would contain a member that is  an `octree_type` itself, that would contain a member that is  an `octree_type` itself, that would finally crash your computer. That is why that is not allowed.

Comment: @kvantour, if there is no `pointer` (or `allocatable` attribute) on the `type(octree_type)` components, then it shouldn't crash the program at run time: the compiler should refuse to compile the invalid code.

Comment: Sorry I did not get that. my `parent` and `children` are pointers regardless of whether I declare my `octree_node` as a pointer or not right? I just want to know what the difference is between having `type(OCTREE_TYPE),pointer        :: octree_node` and `type(OCTREE_TYPE)        :: octree_node`. 
Both seem to work, and just wanted to make sure I am completely aware of what I am doing. Thanks

Comment: @francescalus, yes I was looking it up just to be sure before I made that statement.

Comment: @A2LBK Sorry, it was not clear to me if you were talking about the delcarations inside your type or not.

Comment: Yes, to second, kvantour's comment: please clarify which `pointer` attribute you are uncertain of.  That of the components of the type (`parent` and `children`), or the object (`octree_node`) of that type.

Comment: I meant the declaration outside, my declarations inside is because I want a linkedlist type of thing.
@francescalus the declaration of octree_node

Comment: But what if I don't declare neither with pointer nor with allocatable, is the only difference that I only have one instance of that object , while with pointer and allocatable I can have an array of these objects?

Comment: @francescalus Should I delete my comments, maybe better?

Comment: @kvantour, useful background of the confusion, I feel.  At least until we understand the question fully.

Comment: _"with pointer and allocatable I can have an array of these objects"_. What do you mean? You will have an array whenever you declare a `dimension` attribute. That has nothing to do with the `pointer` or `allocatable` attributes.

Comment: I rarely use pointers, but had a similar looking structure which was rank 6 and terminated in a 1k structure of a 2x integer(kind=C_Int8_t) vector which looks like a complex(kind=1) (value/mask pairs). The target was allocated, and then I pointed the pointer to the relavent vector for managing the vector which was needed. The OP's example would likely be better if it was more fleshed out as a complete example. I only use pointers when there seems no straight forward solution without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference (...) besides that one of them is a pointer and the other is not.

Err... actually, that is the only difference between them: *one is a pointer variable, the other is a normal variable*. Any other difference derives from such fact. If you are already comfortable with how pointer variables work in Fortran, this answer stops here. In case you're not, here is a brief description.

Variables in Fortran are named references to addresses in memory that contains values, that conform in type and characteristics to those in the variable's declaration. When you operate on a variable, its corresponding value in storage is fetched or updated.

With normal variables, this relation is fixed. The system allocates contiguous storage for its value (and all its components, for a derived type) before it could possibly be used, and release that storage when they wouldn't be used anymore, according to its own criteria. Meanwhile, that variable always references that same address in memory, that is fixed in location and size.

On the other hand, for `pointer` variables, this relation is dynamic. The system does not allocate any storage for its underlying value automatically, the only space a pointer occupies is an integer variable, that will sotre the address that it is currently pointing to. You have 2 ways to make use of it:

1) you can indicate another variable and make your pointer reference the same address in memory that the other variable references. This is called *pointer association*, and makes your pointer variable to work as an alias to that other variable. Pointers in Fortran, unlike in other languages, are typed, and this is awesome. You will only be able to associate a pointer to a variable that conforms with it in type, kind and rank, and also if it is marked with the `target` attribute (or is also a pointer). You can change the target of your pointer whenever you want.

2) you can ask the system to allocate a new storage in memory for this variable with the `allocate` statement. This is desirable when you want to control when the storage will be allocated or deallocated and fit it to your program needs. Also, you can defer details of the variable to be decided at runtime, like the size/bounds of an array or `len` parameters of a parameterized type. Be aware that when you choose this way, **you** are in charge of the management of its memory. If you changed your reference to another address without deallocating the previous one, there may be no other reference to that memory and nor you or the system will be able to free it, and memory leaks will happen.

So, to sum up and answer: with the `pointer` attribute, you can use this variable to point to and operate other variables, without requiring memory allocation, acd change the target as you want OR you can manage memory for this variable manually, deferring its size, bounds and length to runtime.

---

Said that, I must remind you of the compromises that comes with the flexibility pointers bring to you. There are lots of gotchas and subtleties when handling pointers, such as memory leaks, dangling pointers, access violation, aliasing..., that could generate errors or performance loss. If the only thing you want for pointers is the dynamic memory allocation part, and don't plan to change its target, you should use the `allocatable` attribute instead. Allocatable variables and components also have dynamic memory, but the system will manage the deallocation for you, although you can also `deallocate` manually.